# Argument 4 to function 'texelFetchOffset' must be a constant expression

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, gaussian

Following an example from the GLSL Cookbook, I am using this code:

```
vec4 Pass2(){
ivec2 pix = ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy);
vec4 sum = texelFetch(texSampler, pix, 0) * weight[0];
for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
    ivec2 posPixOffs = ivec2(0, pixOffset[i]);
    ivec2 negPixOffs = ivec2(0, -pixOffset[i]);
    sum += texelFetchOffset(texSampler, pix, 0, posPixOffs) * weight[i];
    sum += texelFetchOffset(texSampler, pix, 0, negPixOffs) * weight[i];
}
return sum;
}
```

where `pixOffset[]` is defined as

```
uniform int pixOffset[5] = int[](0, 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

and `weight[]` is just a `uniform float` set from the client side of the application.

The `texelFetch` function produces the error in the title.
What qualifies as a contant expression and why is this not considered one?

Comment: and the signature of `texelFetchOffset` is?

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to assign constant values to an uniform array. It might work, but it's not part of the specifications.

A constant expression is something like:

```
const int pixOffset[5] = int[](0, 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Comment: I tried that too, thinking logically that it would work. But I still got the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

The offset is supposed to be a compile-time constant. If you pass value obtained from a constant array by index, the code will normally work only if the loop can be unrolled, so that the individual texelFetchOffset calls end up with constants for the offsets.

On Nvidia it usually works, but AMD drivers often do not unroll the loops, perhaps because of more efficient loop implementation. In that case the offset expression is not constant anymore, and loops with texelFetchOffset fail to compile or link.

Answer (score 1):

First, answering your question on

> What qualifies as a constant expression and why is this not considered one?

According to the [Khronos website](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Constant_expression), to be considered a constant expression, an expression must follow one of the rules below:

> - A literal value.
> - A const-qualified variable (not a function parameter)
>     with an explicit initializer, but only if the initializer is itself
>     one of the following:
>
>   - A constant expression.
>   - An Initializer List, whose components are themselves constant expressions. Initializer lists are not expressions themselves.
> - The result of the length() function of an array, but only if the array has an explicit size (who's size must be a constant expression).
> - The result of most
>     operators, so long as all the operands are themselves constant
>     expressions. The operators not on this list are any assignment
>     operators (+= and so forth), and the comma operator.
> - The result of a constructor for a type, but only if all of the arguments to the
>     constructor are themselves constant expressions.
> - The return value of any built-in function, but only if all of the arguments to the function are themselves constant expressions. Opaque Types are never constant expressions. Note that the functions dFdx, dFdy, fwidth, and their Coarse and Fine variations will return 0, when given a constant expression as an argument.

Also, according to Khronos on [Uniforms](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)), although Uniforms are implicitly const, they are not Constant Expressions.

Changing `pixOffset` as `const`, as stated by David Karlsson above, should fix it:

```
const int PixOffset[5] = int[](0,1,2,3,4);
```

If it doesn't then the problem is that your GPU is probably not unrolling the `for-loop`. Thus, the `i` variable is not constant and the expression `ivec2(0,  PixOffset[i])` is also not constant. If it is the case, you either have to unroll it manually (like I did below) or use another strategy (like, `sum += texelFetch(Texture0, pix + vec2(PixOffset[i], 0), 0) * Weight[0];`).

```
vec4 sum = texelFetch(textureUniform, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), 0) * gaussianWeight[0];
sum += texelFetchOffset(textureUniform, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), 0, ivec2( PixOffset[0], 0)) * gaussianWeight[0];
sum += texelFetchOffset(textureUniform, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), 0, ivec2(-PixOffset[0], 0)) * gaussianWeight[0];
sum += texelFetchOffset(textureUniform, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), 0, ivec2( PixOffset[1], 0)) * gaussianWeight[1];
sum += texelFetchOffset(textureUniform, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), 0, ivec2(-PixOffset[1], 0)) * gaussianWeight[1];
...
```